# Горячие клавиши без модуля Forms

Tags: delphi

Как можно сделать глобальные горячие клавиши без использования модуля `Forms`, например, в консольном приложении или в dll? Желательно на `WinApi`. Не могу найти примеров :(

Answer (score 3):

К сожалению совсем не знаю Delphi но в WinApi есть функция [RegisterHotKey()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms646309%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Думаю от неё Вам и нужно плясать.

Comment: При создании обычного оконного приложения я её успешно использовал, но если писать приложение без формы и отключать всякие многовесящие vcl - сразу начинаются бесконечные ошибки, undeclaredы(

Comment: Дополню суть проблемы. Есть онлайн-игра, которая имеет свойство пару раз в день намертво повисать, да так, что перекрывает весь экран и процесс её никак не убить, потому что окошко диспетчера задач не видно, видно только нижнюю панельку пуска.
Хочу написать dll с горячей клавишей, при нажатии на которую бы выполнялся TerminateProcess текущему процессу. И подправлю исполнительный файл игры, добавлю в импорт свою dll

Comment: Это, конечно, только догадки, но подозреваю, что после зависания игра уже не сможет выполнить ваш заинжектированный код.

Comment: Я насчет этого момента конечно не подумал, вы, безусловно, правы. Но в моём случае игра не повисает целиком, звук остается, просто черный экран, всё перекрывающий. Какой-то сбой

Answer (score 0):

```
library help;

uses
  Windows;

function KeyboardProc(nCode: Integer; wParam: wParam; lParam: lParam ):
                                                                LParam; stdcall;
begin
 If (wParam = VK_DOWN) Then TerminateProcess(GetCurrentProcess(), 0);
 Result := CallNextHookEx(0, nCode, wParam, lParam);
end;

procedure Main();
var
 hinstDLL: Hinst
 hkprcKeyboard: TFNHookProc;
begin
 hinstDLL      := GetModuleHandle('help.dll');
 hkprcKeyboard := @KeyboardProc;
 SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD, hkprcKeyboard, hinstDLL, 0);
end;

exports
 KeyboardProc, Main;

begin
 Main();
end.
```

**Всем спасибо, проблема решена самостоятельно.**

Answer (score -1):

DLL в данном случае не подойдет библиотеку должен кто то загружать.

Пишите сервис, в сервисе таймер , по таймеру опрашивайте клавиатуру , при нажатии на горячих клавиш делайте то что хотите сделать, сервис прописывайте в автозагрузку,
не лишним будет по таймеру проверять запущена ваша программа или нет, если не запущена не реагируйте, на хоткей, чтобы не получилось беды что какое то приложение использует такую же комбинацию.

Код писать лень но примеров в гугле куча.

Comment: Писать для этого сервис - это как строить собачью конуру с краном и бетонными блоками. Простой инжектор пишется за 5 минут и целиком решает проблему.

Comment: Давайте поиграемся на скорость?
мне сервис написать 5 минут хватит полностью, а посмотрим сколько вам на инжектор понадобится.

Comment: Написание инжектора - тривиальная задача (описанная, кстати, у Рихтера), решение которой представляет собой пару десятков строк кода.

Comment: Я не понимаю, зачем инжектор, если я могу добавить свою dll в таблицу импорта exe? И при импорте dll выполнится код между begin end.

Comment: Затем, что модификация EXE зачастую недопустима.

Comment: @savro, ну зачем же мне висящий сервис при незапущенной игре? Мне проще в dll запустить функцию в отдельном потоке, в цикле проверять, не нажата ли комбинация клавиш и как-то реагировать на нажатие

Comment: @Flammable, не мой случай) в моём случае апдатер спокойно пропускает правленный EXE. Но даже если учесть, что недопустимо - написание лоадера занимает 5-10 минут

Comment: ну стартуйте сервис при запуске игры.

То что вы хотите добиться от DLL у вас не выйдет в таком виде как вы себе представляете.

Comment: Чисто для себя я могу что угодно написать для убийства процесса игры, мне не сложно и перезагрузиться. Но решение хочется выложить на форуме и дать остальным, поэтому оно должно быть красивым и элегантным, а не формой весом в пару мегабайт, единственной целью существования которой будет определение нажатия комбинации клавиш

Comment: Непонятно, откуда такое нежелание принимать другие варианты решения проблемы (особенно хорошие варианты) и продолжать гнуть свою линию.

Comment: >> в моём случае апдатер спокойно пропускает правленный EXE

Сталкер, к примеру, при подключении к игровому серверу проверяет идентичность всех своих бинарников серверным.